# Dual Boot win 10 and ubuntu 16.04.1 / Grub2 failed to load windows boot loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

1st i have done a clean installation of windows 10 build 1607 in c Drive which is dev/sda4  in UEFI Mode /GPT partition Scheme,
then installed ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on a unallocated Space as dev/sda6 (Primary) and sda7 as swap area respectively, # prefered during installation alongside windows 10. also uefi moode
After installation finished windows boot loader appeared in grub 2 menu:
[image]

but when i clicked to enter in to windows boot loader it failed to load win 10
and redirected a error message:
[image]

anyone have solution for the issue.
tried update grub from terminal but no result.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off secure boot, and try again.  That's bug 1091464, still a problem on some machines apparently -- for the first time I did see a successful secure boot enabled Windows boot from grub this month, so maybe a fix is in the works.

Answer (score 0):

In the grub menu, select the advanced option (which is just below Ubuntu option in Grub menu) and press "Enter" and then run Ubuntu in recovery mode. Then there you will find a menu and select the update grub option. It will find and fix the Win 10 boot loader. 
Hope this will work for you. Thanks!